# Error launching executable jar - "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, manifest

I'm trying to open my jar using a .sh file. I'm running into this error though:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.mpolder.harambot.Main

As far as I know it exists and should work, this is what my classes look like:
[Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsaw2.png)

And here's my MANIFEST.MF

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
>
> Built-By: Martijn
>
> Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
>
> Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_131
>
> Main-Class: com.mpolder.harambot.Main

Comment: Does it work if you invoke it from the command line instead of from a shell script? And could you verify with unzip or jar -tf that the class is actually in the jar?

Comment: This is the output I get when running jar -tf. http://puu.sh/xBcnR/8036cb199e.png

Answer (score 0):

Found it, had to export as a fat jar to include dependencies